# JQuery event handlers firing before event occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'm trying to add event handlers to a series of divs using a for loop. What should happen is that when I click a #containingThumbs div, its corresponding #content div should be displayed. At first, I ran into the issue where assigning event handlers in a for loop meant that no matter what #containingThumbs div I clicked, only the last #content div would appear.

I fixed that, by calling to an external function instead of defining one in the event handler itself, but now for some reason, all the event handlers on every #containingThumbs div fires as soon as the page is loaded. After that, clicking on the divs does nothing whatsoever.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="containingThumbs">
<div><img src="1.png"></div>
<div><img src="2.png"></div>
<div><img src="3.png"></div>
<div><img src="4.png"></div>
<div><img src="5.png"></div>
<div><img src="6.png"></div>
<div><img src="7.png"></div>
<div><img src="8.png"></div>
<div><img src="9.png"></div>
<div><img src="10.png"></div>
<div><img src="11.png"></div>
<div><img src="3.png"></div>
<div><img src="4.png"></div>
<div><img src="5.png"></div>
<div><img src="6.png"></div>
<div><img src="7.png"></div>
<div><img src="8.png"></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div><img src="1.png"></div>
<div><img src="2.png"></div>
<div><img src="3.png"></div>
<div><img src="4.png"></div>
<div><img src="5.png"></div>
<div><img src="6.png"></div>
<div><img src="7.png"></div>
<div><img src="8.png"></div>
<div><img src="9.png"></div>
<div><img src="10.png"></div>
<div><img src="11.png"></div>
<div><img src="3.png"></div>
<div><img src="4.png"></div>
<div><img src="5.png"></div>
<div><img src="6.png"></div>
<div><img src="7.png"></div>
<div><img src="8.png"></div>
</div>
```

and here's the relevant JS/JQuery code:

```
function expandDiv(j){
    //first hide all content that is currently displayed, if any
    $("#content div").css("display","none");
    //then display only the right content div
    $("#content div:nth-child("+j+")").css("display","inherit"); 
}

function makeInteractive(){
    for (var i = 0;i<$("#containingThumbs").children().length;i++){
        $("#containingThumbs").on("click","div",expandDiv(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
$("#containingThumbs").on("click","div",expandDiv(i));
```

**calls** `expandDiv` and passes its return value into `on`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes the result into `foo`. What you pass into `on` should be a function reference.

Several ways to correct that code:

1. If you just want `i` because you want to know which div was clicked, you don't need it; within the call to `expandTab`, `this` will refer to the DOM element for the div. So if you change `expandTab` to use `this`, you can just remove the `(i)` after `expandTab`:

   ```
   function makeInteractive(){
       for (var i = 0;i<$("#containingThumbs").children().length;i++){
           $("#containingThumbs").on("click","div",expandTab);
           // No (i) ---------------------------------------^
       }
   }
   ```

   Again, you'd have to change `expandTab` to use `this` for the div.
2. You can pass `i` using a closure:

   ```
   function makeInteractive(){
       for (var i = 0;i<$("#containingThumbs").children().length;i++){
           $("#containingThumbs").on("click","div",makeHandler(i));
       }
       function makeHandler(index) {
           return expandDiv(index);
       }
   }
   ```

   That assumes `expandTab` is expecting to see that index as its first argument, and isn't using the event object.
3. Or if you want to change `expandDiv` a bit, you can handle it by having jQuery pass you the extra argument as [event data](http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data):

   ```
   function makeInteractive(){
       for (var i = 0;i<$("#containingThumbs").children().length;i++){
           $("#containingThumbs").on("click", "div", i, expandDiv);
           // Note the `i` --------------------------^           ^--- no ()
       }
   }
   ```

   `expandDiv` would use `event.data` as the index.

Comment: I'm trying method 1 right now, so my line of code is
    $("#containingThumbs").on("click","div",expandDiv);
but now I'm getting a "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child" error message because the function input is an event, but I need an index value to know which #content div to display.

Comment: ...also trying method 2 gives me a "Uncaught TypeError: Object div has no method 'apply'" error that I don't understand. And method 3...appears to fire all the events the same way as when the page first loads with no visible effect.

Comment: @user3060388: Again, see the notes above. You said you tried method 1, but you talked about using an index where I've clearly told you that using method 1 you'd have to use `this` instead. You've about using method 2, but using the event object, and I've clearly said "That assumes `expandTab` is expecting to see that index as its first argument, and isn't using the event object." With method 3, again as I've said, you'd use `event.data` for the index.

Comment: Ah, got it! Thank you so much, I didn't quite understand what you meant at first but using method 1 and replacing i in expandDiv with $(this).index()+1 did the trick! It's working perfectly now.